# MVC - Best/cleanest way to use data from multiple view models in a single view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

I'm still learning the ropes of MVC.  I know this question is probably MVC 101, but I'm having trouble figuring out the best way to go about it:
**What's the best way to take the data from 2 view models & use it in a single view?**

I inherited an application which has a bunch of email templates setup via Views.  These templates all utilize the same view model:

```
@model MyCompany.Mvc.MyApplication.Models.Emails.EmailTemplateViewModel
```

So far, this has worked for all templates because the template data is rather generic.  It's really more a matter of setting up the html design of the different views around the generic email data.

Now however, they want an email template that sort of breaks that mold.  It's still a template & includes the data within the "**EmailTemplates**" model, but it ALSO needs to include add'l information, which is all already contained within a separate view model:

```
@model CustomerViewModel
```

What's the best way to go about pulling from both of these models for my new email template view?

So, as a quick example, here would be my models:

**EmailTemplateViewModel**

```
public class EmailTemplateViewModel
{

    public string TodaysDateLongFormat
    {
        get
        {
            DateTime value = DateTime.Now;

            return value.ToString("MMMM") + " " + value.Day + ToOrdinal(value.Day) + ", " + value.Year;
        }
    }
}
```

**CustomerViewModel**

```
public class CustomerViewModel
{
     public string CustomerFirstName { get; set; }
     public string CustomerLastName { get;set; }
     public string HasMissingOrderField { get; set; }
 }
```

**NewEmailTemplateView.cshtml** (current multiple model declaration would obviously fail)

```
 @model MyCompany.Mvc.MyApplication.Models.Emails.EmailTemplateViewModel
 @model CustomerViewModel
 <table style="border-top: 5px; padding-bottom: 5px;">
    <tr>
        <td>
            Date: @Model.TodaysDateLongFormat
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Customer First Name: @Model.CustomerFirstName
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Customer Last Name: @Model.CustomerLastName
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

What's the best way to go about this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing wrong with having multiple viewmodels under a parent viewmodel.

```
public class ParentViewModel
{
    public ChildViewModel1 ChildViewModel1 { get; set; }
    public ChildViewModel2 ChildViewModel2 { get; set; }
}
```

You can then set the model in your view to  `@model ParentViewModel`, after which you can access each child viewmodel (and it's respective properties) using the usual Razor syntax:

`@Model.ChildViewModel1.Property1`, `@Model.ChildViewModel2.Property3`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

I think the best answer here is to build just one proper View Model and fill it with required data with a controller.

**NewEmailTemplateViewModel**

```
public class NewEmailTemplateViewModel
{
     public CustomerViewModel Customer { get; set; }
     public EmailTemplateViewModel Email { get; set; }
}
```

**NewEmailTemplateView.cshtml**

```
@model MyCompany.Mvc.MyApplication.Models.Emails.NewEmailTemplateViewModel

 <table style="border-top: 5px; padding-bottom: 5px;">
    <tr>
        <td>
            Date: @Model.Email.TodaysDateLongFormat
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Customer First Name: @Model.Customer.CustomerFirstName
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Customer Last Name: @Model.Customer.CustomerLastName
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

and in controller just create your view model and assign properties:

```
var model = new NewEmailTemplateViewModel();
model.Customer = your customerViewModel;
model.Email = your modelViewModel;
return model;
```